Pattern in Java cannot accurately handle Turkish characters
I am working on a profanity/insult blocking system in Minecraft. However, I am facing an issue with Turkish characters in the pattern system. The problem is as follows:
When I type 'bit' in the game chat, it should be blocked, but when I type 'bıt', it should not be blocked. The system treats both as the same and blocks the one that shouldn't be blocked.
The code is as follows:
public Boolean CheckIt(String word1, String list) {
    List<String> words = this.getConfig().getStringList(list);
    String word = word1.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
    for (String wordControl : words) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\b" + wordControl + "\\b", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.UNICODE_CASE);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(word);
        Matcher matcher1 = pattern.matcher(word1);

        if (matcher.find() || matcher1.find()) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

I tried different pattern parameters and aimed to differentiate between the letters 'ı' and 'i', but I couldn't achieve this.

Why do you need to block the whole message, when you could just replace it's charachters with _?

Unfortunately I can't change the characters. if this message is completely blocked, players will be subject to temporary silence. I can't deviate from the purpose of the plugin, unfortunately.

Why Pattern.UNICODE_CASE? This is yet another instance of the Scunthorpe Problem. There is always going to be false positives with a naive pattern matching approach.

When Pattern.UNICODE_CASE was removed, there was no problem with lowercase letters, but this time I am having a problem with uppercase Turkish characters.

If you're operating on whole words, why use regex at all?

Actually, the words in a message are important to me. If you have a suggestion, I'd like to hear it.

Case insensitive matching words against the list?

No, it is all lowercase.

You could always remove the CASE_INSENSITIVE and UNICODE_CASE flags, and define your words internally as "[Bb][İi][Tt]" etc.

I removed Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE and Pattern.UNICODE_CASE and added the word1.toLowerCase(Locale.forLanguageTag("tr")); code along with the double matcher, and I was able to solve the problem. Still, I want to thank everyone for their suggestions and ideas.
